# Getting "image" from outside Java screen resources

Tags: java, image-processing

Suppose I wish to start a program within a JFrame, as is normal, but I want the program to be able to access and manipulate a rectangular block of the full computer screen (Macintosh) that
is outside of the program's frame.

By "manipulate", in this case, I intend to apple some pattern recognition schemes, and I would need to be able to read individual pixels.

Any ideas as to how to get started on such an effort would be appreciated.

John Doner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Robot class has a method, [createScreenCapture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29), for getting a screen capture and storing it as a BufferedImage which then can be manipulated via the Java Imaging libraries.  You'll need to import or create the pattern recognition libraries, I believe.

Comment: Thanks.  That appears to be just the ticket.